# SWIG syntax error in C struct declaration

Tags: c, swig

I am trying to wrap the following header using SWIG Python, and I get the error:

> Error: Syntax error in input(1).

This error, at least according to the build statement, happens at the `struct complex` declaration.

```
#ifndef _RMATH_H
#define _RMATH_H

#ifndef _COMPLEX
struct complex {  // error happens here 
    float x,y;
};
#define cabs(a) sqrt((a.x*a.x)+(a.y*a.y))
#endif

#endif
```

I know SWIG is not compatible with some C variables; what is wrong with this one?

Comment: Identifiers starting with an underscore and an uppercase letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't define such identifiers in your own code (unless you're writing code that's part of the C implementation, such as the standard library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is SWIG's handling of the identifier `complex`.

SWIG does not invoke an external C compiler to parse header files; it has its own parser for C and C++. C99 [introduces support for complex numbers](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html). SWIG is attempting to support C complex numbers, but is treating `complex` as a keyword, which is different from how `complex` is treated in C (where it is a macro defined in [*complex.h*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/complex.h.html)).

In the depths of SWIG's implementation, it can be seen that this handling of `complex` as a keyword by the SWIG parser applies only in C mode, not in C++ mode (note the `cparse_cplusplus` variable being checked):

> ```
>   if (!cparse_cplusplus && (strcmp(c, "float complex") == 0))
>     return T_FLTCPLX;
>   if (!cparse_cplusplus && (strcmp(c, "double complex") == 0))
>     return T_DBLCPLX;
>   if (!cparse_cplusplus && (strcmp(c, "complex") == 0))
>     return T_COMPLEX;
> ```

And this header is indeed accepted by SWIG when run with the `-c++` parameter.

If building as C++ isn't an option, you could rename your `struct` to something else (e.g. `Complex`).

If the header definitions aren't under your control, you could take a sledgehammer approach with the pre-processor, by `#define`-ing `complex` to an acceptable alternative name instead, e.g. putting the following in your SWIG module interface *.i* file:

```
#define complex Complex
%include "rmath.h" // Or whatever your header is called
```

When you're building the generated SWIG C wrapper file, you'll also need to have the same `#define` present before *rmath.h* is included.

Comment: No, neither C99 nor C11 defines `complex` as a keyword. C99 introduced `_Complex` as a keyword. And the header `<complex.h>` has a macro definition `#define complex _Complex`. Avoiding the name `complex` is still a good idea, just to avoid confusion (and syntax errors if you've `#include`d `<complex.h>`).

Comment: @KeithThompson - to clarify, are you disagreeing with the terminology? I was basing on the page I linked to on gnu.org stating "It is a keyword if and only if complex.h has been included.". Would "type qualifier" be preferable? SWIG, however, is treating it as though it were a keyword, which is the problem.

Comment: Yes, the gnu.org page is incorrect. `complex` is *never* a keyword. If `<complex.h>` is included, then `complex` is a macro that expands to a keyword, specifically `_Complex`. (`_Complex` is a keyword regardless of what has or hasn't been included.) I suspect if we could see the error message from the compiler itself (I'm assuming SWIG invokes the compiler), I suspect it would refer to the `_Complex` keyword.

Comment: @KeithThompson, no SWIG doesn't invoke the compiler (which is why the exact terminology and treatment in the C standard is a bit academic here ;-) ). SWIG has its own parser. I was aware of the actual implementation being of the form you describe in *complex.h*, but didn't see any reason to get into the nuances, because the OP's issue is how SWIG is treating `complex`, not how a C compiler would treat it.

Comment: @KeithThompson I've updated the answer to clarify that SWIG does its own parsing, and that this is not the way a C compiler would treat the identifier `complex`.

Comment: I presume you know more about SWIG than I do (that would not be difficult). But I'm surprised SWIG would work this way. Doesn't it have to invoke something very much like the C preprocessor anyway? If so, the obvious approach would be to treat `_Complex` as a keyword, and `complex` as an ordinary identifier that gets expanded to `_Complex` if `<complex.h>` is included. The alternative would be for SWIG's input to be a restricted subset of C, with `complex` handled as an ugly special case.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I agree that it would be great if SWIG worked with real C and C++ compilers as the back-end. Even for the relatively straightforward task of preprocessing (which it also does itself) I have run into some strange bugs in the past (which I assume arise from SWIG not actually treating the preprocessor entirely as a separate step, because it can wrap up preprocessor definitions as constants in the target language for example). The fact that SWIG has rolled-its-own C and C++ header parsing means that inevitably idiosyncracies like the one that the OP has run into do crop up.